# java split Styleddocument into two

Tags: java, swing, split, document, rtf

I have a DefaultStyledDocument with a formatted Text inside. I also have a function, which splits the content (as plainText) with a Pattern-Matcher.

I need a function, which generates from the splitted output new complete DefaultStyledDocuments

```
DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
Functions.loadRtfToDocument(rtfText, doc); //rtfText is a RTF-String

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((\\s*)•)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(plainText);
while(matcher.find()){
    int start = matcher.start();
    int end = matcher.end();
    DefaultStyledDocument target = new DefaultStyledDocument();
    //Fill the target with the styled text (from start to end)
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [jrtf](https://code.google.com/p/jrtf/)?

Comment: hi, no, i use RTFEditorKit... is jrtf able to split the document into two? (e.g. split at list elements)

Answer (score 1):

It's not trivial task. Imagine your start position found in the mid of nested table and end position is in the mid of ordered list placed after base table.

For the simplest cas when you have only paragaraphs and texts in the document you can go through all paragraph elements asking their start and end offsets and compare with matcher's offsets. If the paragraph suits the range go through paragraph element's childrent (text elements). For each text element which suits given range just call insertString() in the target document passing text and attributes from the text element.

Comment: hi, yes there are only paragraphs (with lists and texts) included. so no complex elements like tables, images et.